# how to create a xml document on the fly with xquery?

Tags: xml, xquery

I what to use XQuery to convert string like "aaa=1&bbb=2" into xml

```
<request>
  <aaa>1</aaa>
  <bbb>2</bbb>
</request>
```

I have tried the following code, but failed!

```
xquery version "1.0" encoding "GBK";
(:: pragma  type="xs:anyType" ::)

declare namespace xf = "http://tempuri.org/BNetAP/Xquery/query2xml/";

declare function xf:query2xml($queryStr as xs:string)
    as element(*) {
    <query-params>
    {
        for $c in
            fn:tokenize($queryStr, "&amp;")
        let $myname as xs:string := "{fn:substring-before($c,"=")}"
        return 
            element
                {fn:QName("", $myname)}
                {"{fn:substring-after($c,"=")}"}
    }
    </query-params>
};
```

The error message is:

```
line 15, column 6:  "{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}QName": unknown function (or number of arguments (2) is wrong)  BNetAP/Xquery   query2xml.xq    line 15 1241431186406   397
```

I have no idea why "QName" is a "unknow function"?!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the constructor xs:QName, not fn:QName.

The body of your constructed element also looks a bit suspicious:

```
"{fn:substring-after($c,"=")}"
```

is in fact a comparison between the string "{fn:substring-after($c," and the string ")}"
so the content of the element would just be the text "false".

Similarly you $myname variable is actually being set to false and so will raise a type check error at run time.

Your function should probably be as follows:

```
declare function xf:query2xml($queryStr as xs:string)
    as element(*) {
  <query-params>
  {
    for $c in fn:tokenize($queryStr, "&amp;")
    let $myname := fn:substring-before($c,"=")
    return 
      element
        {xs:QName("", $myname)}
        {fn:substring-after($c,"=")}
  }
  </query-params>
};
```

A computed element constructor can also accept just a string for its name, so your return expression could be simplified to just

```
return element {$myname} {fn:substring-after($c,"=")}
```